# UiTableViewHeader - Dynamic button event handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to add a uiButton to a static uitableview section header - I've made an attempt with the following -

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // you can get the title you statically defined in the storyboard
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    CGRect frame = tableView.bounds;
    // create and return a custom view
    #define LABEL_PADDING 10.0f
    HeaderLabelStyling *customLabel = [[HeaderLabelStyling alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(frame, LABEL_PADDING, 0)] ;

    UIButton *addButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width-60, 10, 50, 30)];

    addButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    addButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0f green:118/255.0f blue:34/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    addButton.titleLabel.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
    title.text = @"iawn";

    customLabel.text = sectionTitle;

    customLabel.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:143.0f/255.0f green:137.0f/255.0f blue:135.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    customLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    [customLabel addSubview:addButton];
    [addButton addSubview:title];
     [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(receiverButtonClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
return customLabel;
}

-(void)receiverButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"button clicked");
}
```

the above adds a button - but doesn't react to the click event - can anyone suggest how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UILabel` does not handles touches by default.

Add following line of code:

```
customLabel.userInteractionsEnabled = YES;
```

In order to display button only for third section you should add following condition:

```
if(section == 2){...}
```

So your `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` should look as follows:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection (NSInteger)section {
    if(section != 2) return nil;
    // you can get the title you statically defined in the storyboard
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    CGRect frame = tableView.bounds;
    // create and return a custom view
    #define LABEL_PADDING 10.0f
    HeaderLabelStyling *customLabel = [[HeaderLabelStyling alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(frame, LABEL_PADDING, 0)] ;

    UIButton *addButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width-60, 10, 50, 30)];

    addButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    addButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0f green:118/255.0f blue:34/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    addButton.titleLabel.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 30)];
    title.text = @"iawn";

    customLabel.text = sectionTitle;

    customLabel.backgroundColor= [UIColor colorWithRed:143.0f/255.0f green:137.0f/255.0f blue:135.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    customLabel.userInteractionsEnabled = YES;
    customLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    [customLabel addSubview:addButton];
    [addButton addSubview:title];
     [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(receiverButtonClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
return customLabel;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can check my update for full answer.